# How do I automatically populate the options of a select element in HTML using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

First and foremost first time posting a question be easy on me please :)

I am trying to generate a `Form DropDownList (Select/options) using PHP/MySQL. I need the options to automatically populate using tablenames from my database that only contain ".com"

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
$db = mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '%.com%'",$con) or die('cannot show tables');
while($tableName = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$table = $tableName[0];
}
;
$option .= '<option value = "website-manager.php?table='.$table.'">'.$table.'</option>';
?>
<form name="form" id="form">
  <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu">
    <option value="#">Select Website</option>
    <?php echo $option ; ?>
  </select>
  <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="Go" onclick="MM_jumpMenuGo('jumpMenu','parent',0)" />
</form>
```

When I use this code, only one tablename populates as opposed to the 15 currently in my database.

How can I correct my code above to populate all of the tablenames?

Comment: Do your table names actually contain dots? I thought that is a reserved character, and it isn't available for use for table/column names. Would you give examples of some of the table names you have?

Comment: Hey Halfer yes my tablenames are automatically generated. I am building a multisite CMS and the website builder function allows me to decide the website name and url. the URL is what actually becomes the DB tablename. It allows me to make it more unique and prevents multiple websites of the same url to be built.

Comment: Hmm, not an approach I'd recommend, in all honesty. Have a lookup table that converts your URL into a table name containing safe characters, or -- better still -- put everything into one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested move `}` of while end below - Try replacing part with this:

```
<?php
$filter = '%wp_%';
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pwd");
$db = mysql_select_db("enterDbName",$con);
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$filter."'",$con) or die('cannot show tables');
$option = '';
while($tableName = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $table = $tableName[0];
    $option .= '<option value = "website-manager.php?table='.$table.'">'.$table.'</option>';
}
?><form name="form" id="form">
    <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu">
        <option value="#">Select Website</option>
        <?php echo $option ; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="Go" onclick="MM_jumpMenuGo('jumpMenu','parent',0)" />
</form>
```

**Warning**: This extension (`mysql`) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: So I made the update as you suggested but what happens is the option dropdownlist only displays 1 website option Although there are 15 tables in the DB that contain the filter I am looking for. Seems like something could be missing as far as getting multiple tablenames in the option dropdownlist.

Comment: Nevermind folks i think i figured out why my filter wasn't working. I was looking to have the filter search for ".com". by simply removing the "." from the filter all my Website TableNames populated! thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are overwriting `$table` with each iteration through the DB result set.

You need to put the data into an array like this:

```
$tables = array();
while ($tableName...) {
    $tables[] = $tableName[0];
}
```

Then output your options in a loop like this:

```
<option value="#">Select Website</option>
<?php
foreach($tables as $table) {
    echo '<option value="website-manager.php?table=' . urlencode($table) .'">' . $table . </option>';
}
?>
```